# Не работает If и выдаёт ошибку

Tags: c#, if

Ошибка - Необработанное исключение типа "System.IO.FileNotFoundException" в Неизвестный модуль.
Не удалось загрузить файл или сборку "System.Runtime, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" либо одну из их зависимостей. Не удается найти указанный файл.

Только начал изучать C# помогите

```
using System;

namespace Калькулятор
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите первое число");
            string X = Console.ReadLine();
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(X);
            Console.WriteLine("Введите второе число");
            string Y = Console.ReadLine();
            int y = Convert.ToInt32(Y);

            if(x == y)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Эти числа равны");
            }
            else if (x != y)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Эти числа не равны");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Что тут вообще написано?");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А в каком случае по-вашему будет написано "Что тут вообще написано?"

Comment: Проблема не в коде, который вы показали. / Проект какого типа вы создали? / Какие библиотеки/сборки/пакеты подключали? И как подключали?